# Too many nested function calls in XSLT -- tail recursive?

Tags: xml, recursion, xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon

I have a recursive function in my XSLT. It is meant to identify "chains" of elements, where a chain is defined as sequence of  elements with start(n+1)=end(n), for example:

```
<!-- first chain starts here -->
<event start="T0" end="T1">doo</event>
<event start="T1" end="T2">doo</event>
<event start="T2" end="T3">doo</event>
<!-- first chain ends here -->
<event start="T4" end="T5">doo</event>
<event start="T5" end="T6">doo</event>
```

I am using the following recursive function:

```
<!-- returns latest event that is connected to the given event through an uninterrupted chain of other events -->
<xsl:function name="exmaralda:last-endpoint-of-segment-chain">
    <xsl:param name="event"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not($event/following-sibling::event) or exmaralda:timeline-position($event/following-sibling::event[1]/@start)&gt;exmaralda:timeline-position($event/@end)">
            <xsl:value-of select="$event/@end"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="exmaralda:last-endpoint-of-segment-chain($event/following-sibling::event[1])"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>        
</xsl:function>
```

This works fine as long as sequences of events are not too long (they usually comprise no more than 10 elements). However, if they have a length above a certain value, the transformation throws an error "Too many nested function calls in XSLT". I have read that, in order to avoid this, recursive functions should be made tail-recursive. However, I cannot see why my recursion would **not** have that property. Can anybody see what might be wrong here?

I am using Saxon 9he as the XSL engine.

Comment: Saxon has some documentation on how to achieve tail recursion, see the relevant section in https://www.saxonica.com/documentation10/index.html#!xsl-elements/function

Answer (score 1):

Assuming XSLT 3 (supported since 9.8) it seems to identify the "chains" you can use `group-adjacent`:

```
  <xsl:template match="events">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="event" composite="yes" group-adjacent="@end => substring-after('T') => xs:integer() - position(), @start => substring-after('T') => xs:integer() - (position() + 1)">
        <chain>
          <xsl:sequence select="current-group()"/>
        </chain>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nbspVax

A more general and precise declarative grouping implementation might be possible in XSLT using `break-when`, currently supported by SaxonCS and hopefully soon by Saxon 11:

```
  <xsl:template match="events">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="event" break-when="$next/@start => substring-after('T') => xs:integer() gt $group[last()]/@end => substring-after('T') => xs:integer()">
        <chain>
          <xsl:sequence select="current-group()"/>
        </chain>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason your function isn't tail-recursive is that a tail-recursive function must return the result of the recursive call as is, without further processing. Your call requests further processing: the `xsl:value-of` instruction asks for the result to be converted to a text node.

Saxon can sometimes work out that you didn't really want this conversion, but it can only do that if you declare the type of the function result.

So you should make two improvements to your code, both of which are standard good coding practice: (a) use `xsl:sequence` rather than `xsl:value-of` to return function results, and (b) use an `as` attribute on `xsl:function` and `xsl:param` to declare the types of the function parameters and result.

Furthermore, as Martin points out, it's a good idea to use `xsl:for-each-group` or `xsl:iterate` rather than recursive functions where it makes sense: it usually makes the code more readable and it's often more efficient.

Comment: Perfect, great, fabulous! Made the suggested changes. The transformation takes a couple of seconds, but it terminates with the desired result and without error message. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I would only expect to see an error about too many nested function calls when memory was exhausted, which most commonly happens with a faulty recursion termination test.  (Memory might be exhausted in OP's case, but unless it's a lot more than "10 elements", memory exhaustion seems on the surface to be unlikely.)  Does Saxon have to hard-code a recursion depth limit apart from available memory?

Comment: Also, might want to note explicitly in your answer that the reason tail-recursion can help is that it enables an optimization whereby recursion is converted to iteration by the compiler.

Comment: The error message "too many nested function calls" is caused by Saxon catching a StackOverflow exception. There's no hard-coded limit.

Comment: Good, that's what I hoped to hear.  Thanks.